# AAD Sync not able to connect to online service using powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell, azure, microsoft-office-365

When trying to connect to my Office 365 tenant using connect-msolservice from powershell I get the following error:

```
Connect-MsolService : The HTTP request was forbidden with client
authentication scheme 'Negotiate'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-MsolService -Credential $azcreds
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], Mes
   sageSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityExce
   ption,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolService

Connect-MsolService : Exception of type
'Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineException' was
thrown.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-MsolService -Credential $azcreds
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], Mic
   rosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.Micro
   softOnlineException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsol
```

I can browse to portal.microsoftonline.com from the same machine using the same user account.
Can anyone tell point me in the right direction. Particularly what info I will need to give the Websense engineers?

Answer (score 0):

When you get an error do

```
$error[0] | fl * -f
```

You get a better stack and it gives you an idea of what was attempted.

Looks like you maybe having issues authenticating to a web proxy in order to get to the Azure endpoint.

What authentication does your web proxy (i assume its websense) support? I hope the proxy isn't set just for basic auth support. It need to do Negotiate/Kerberos/NTLM.

Not sure why you mentioned AAD Sync here. You may have to ensure AADSync machine or service account is allowed to access MS destinations anonymously, if your web proxy cant do NTLM/Negotiate.